# Unity - Add object with inherited type to field of the inherited type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a inventory system that takes in an item of type BaseItem. I've extended upon this to add new types of items that inherit from BaseItem, and I'd like to be able to dynamically add those to the inventory or via the editor.

Inventory Slot:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class InventorySlot
{
    public BaseItem item = new BaseItem();
    public int amount;

    public InventorySlot()
    {
        item = new BaseItem();
        amount = 0;
    }

    ect.
}
```

BaseItem:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class BaseItem : ScriptableObject {
    public string name;
    public int id = -1;
    public Sprite uiDisplay;

    public BaseItem() {
        name = "";
        id = -1;
    }

    ect.
}
```

This works perfectly as I'm able to define a bunch of items in the editor and dynamically add them to my inventory. I've tried to extend upon this by adding new item types that extend upon BaseItem such as

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Item", menuName = "Inventory System/Items/magical")]
[System.Serializable]
public class MagicalItem : BaseItem {
    public string passive;

    public MagicalItem(string passive, BaseItem item) : base(item) {
        this.passive = passive;
    }
}
```

but I'm unable to add these items to my inventory slot. Any idea how to allow InventorySlot to take in any type that has a base type of BaseItem?

Thanks!

Comment: Why does the slot create an item at all? This seems to be the actual problem here. I suspect it should instead **recieve** an item by using a constructor-arg.

Comment: InventorySlot is slightly misnamed. This is more a container for holding an item which is used in my inventory display script. I have an inventory "database" of sorts that works in that way, and the slot is just used to display that database.

Comment: then it´s even more suspocious: why should some database *create* an item at all? Instead the client that *uses* that database should create items and add them to the database.

Comment: Well regardless of the implementation of the system, I'm just curious if it's possible to have these inherited types in allowed in a single property in InventorySlot.

Comment: It is **NOT ALLOWED** to have a constructor for any type inheriting from `UnityEngine.Object` nor to use the `new` keyword for creating them! Afaik you should even get a warning about it. If you want to create instances of a `ScriptableObject` you need to go through [`ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<TYPE>`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.CreateInstance.html) .. then you have to call e.g. an `Initialize` method and pass in your arguments

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question

Comment: Have you tried just assigning it to the `item` field? e.g., `public void SetItem(BaseItem newItem) {item = newItem;}` Then elsewhere... `inventorySlotInstance.SetItem(magicalItemInstance);`? Seems like the obvious thing to try, so was there an error you should share with us?

Comment: If you're talking about being unable to assign things in the editor it's probably some kind of compilation error, in which case, there should be an error being shared with us. Is there an error shown in the inspector when you select your instance of `MagicalItem`?

Comment: Whenever you cfreate a slot, you also create an instance of `BaseItem` in the slots ctor. You can overwrite that instance as the slots `Item` is a public field: `mySlot.Item = new MagicalItem()`.

Answer (score 0):

I might misunderstand, but with some minor changes, you can most certainly add inherited scriptable objects to your inventory slot.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class InventorySlot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public BaseItem item;
}
```

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Base Item", menuName = "Inventory System/Items/Base")]
[System.Serializable]
public class BaseItem : ScriptableObject
{
    public string name;
    public int id = -1;
    public Sprite uiDisplay;

    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        name = "";
        id = -1;
    }
}
```

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Magic Item", menuName = "Inventory System/Items/Magical")]
[System.Serializable]
public class MagicalItem : BaseItem
{
    public string passive;

    protected override void Awake()
    {
        base.Awake();
        this.passive = "whatever...";
    }
}
```

Note that scriptable objects should not use the constructor but instead initialize in the Awake() method. I have declared the method as virtual in the base class so we can override it but still call it.

Comment: When I attempt in the editor to add a MagicalItem to InventorySlot I get the following error: 'Type can not be found: MagicalItem. Containing file and class name must match.

Comment: You have the answer in the error message :). Make sure that each scriptable object is in its own file, exactly named as the scriptable object. The "MagicalItem" must be in "MagicalItem.cs" and BaseItem in "BaseItem.cs".